# Why does Steve/Amanda die from child birthing complications?

Tags: plot-explanation, switch

In ***"Switch"*** (1991), the main character Steve, who finds himself in Ellen Barkin's body after being murdered and given a second chance, is impregnated after a night of drinking. While in a mental facility after being framed for his own death, she is expected to give birth because she doesn't want to give the baby up.

She dies giving birth. ***Was there any specific medical reason for her death after child birth?*** what specific reason does she die?

Answer (score 4):

The doctor during her pregnancy consultation tells her that there are complications, and if she carries the baby until full term, she could die<sup>1</sup>.

The death is implied to have needed to happen, as Steve (main character) was given a second chance at life after being killed the first time. By giving birth to a life is redemption for his mostly womanizing habits, earning his/her spot in heaven.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>[LA Times May 1991](http://articles.latimes.com/1991-05-10/entertainment/ca-1304_1_blake-edwards)</sub>